# Loadtesting until server fails

Tags: performance, weblogic, soapui, load-testing

We have an application which we want to load test and the specific question we want to be answered is as follows:

How many requests can our server handle?

**To be even more specific:**

Is it possible (with SOAPUI for example) to increase the load until the server breaks (out of memory) and stop the load test on that very instant (or after the first response that is empty)?

It's concerning a web service which runs on WebLogic.

Comment: May be your first stop should be [documentation](https://www.soapui.org/load-testing/creating-and-running-loadtests.html)

Comment: Anything is possible!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done for instance with [Apache JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/) which provides:

1. Possibility to stop test on any error on [Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) level

   [image: Thread Group Action Sampler Error]
2. Possibility to conditionally fail tests based on wide criteria range via [Assertions](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#assertions)
3. [AutoStop Listener](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/AutoStop/) extension allows to stop the test when i.e. average response time exceeds, or error rate certain threshold

JMeter is a multi-protocol load testing tool which for sure can be used for APIs testing as it evidenced by [Testing SOAP/REST Web Services Using JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/testing-soaprest-web-services-using-jmeter) article, besides it has much better reporting capabilities than SoapUI does.